# Issue with liquid level sensing circuit with LDC0851 chip

Tags: circuit-design, texas-instruments, inductive

I came across a video where TI demonstrates liquid level sensing via an inductive switch. I am trying to recreate this and understand the circuit they made. A [forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/sensors-group/sensors/f/sensors-forum/526822/ldc0851-liquid-level-designs) provided this schematic:

[image: Text]

Below I have attached what my breadboard circuit and setup look like. According to the forum, Rx = 4 kΩ and Ry= 1 kΩ. My container is a plexiglass box and the metal sensors are steel. The forum said that "The output will switch LOW when fsense > fref. Similarly when fsense < fref the output will switch HIGH."

Where am I going wrong (I already tried flipping the ref and the sense)?

[image: Circuit Test Diagram]

Comment: Also note that a solderless breadboard has *horrific* parasitic capacitance.  If intending on making a PCB "eventually", suggest making a prototype PCB *now* because it will behave differently.

Comment: what liquid are you sensing?

Comment: @rdtsc okay thank you, I'll put together something asap

Comment: @jsotola I would like to use this as a way of overfill protection on an oil container. So the liquid would be oil. I do know that the dielectric constant is substantially different from water which could cause an issue.

Comment: @jsotola but just trying to replicate the water level sensing right now to understand if this concept would be a good application for that.

Comment: Why not just use a float switch?

Answer (score 1):

You are connected to the wrong side of the 1k resistors and the black wire from top to bottom is shorting your inputs.  Assuming your resistor values are correct, you should make the connection to the potentiometers on the same side as the incoming signal from the sensing electrodes like so:

[image: updated drawing]